# Batching the send operation on outbound adapter in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-jms

I have an outbound channel adapter (in this case is SFTP but it would be the same for a JMS or WS) at the end of a Spring Integration flow. By using direct channels every time there is a messaging flowing, it will be sent out synchronously.
Now, I need to process messages all the way until they reach the outbound adapter, but wait for a predetermined interval before sending them out. In other words batching the send operation.
I know the Spring Batch project might offer a solution to this but I need to find a solution with Spring Integration compoonents (in the int-* namespaces)
What would be a typical pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Aggregator` [pattern](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator) is for you.

In your particular case I'd call that like [`window`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/window.html), because you don't have any specific correlation to group messages, but just need to build a `batch` as you call it.

So, I think your Aggregator config may look like:

```
<int:aggregator input-channel="input" output-channel="output"
    correlation-strategy-expression="1"
    release-strategy-expression="size() == 10"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"/>
```

- `correlation-strategy-expression="1"` means `group` any incoming messages
- `release-strategy-expression="size() == 10"` allows to form and release batches by 10 messages
- `expire-groups-upon-completion="true"` says to aggregator to remove the releases group from it store. That allow to for a new group for the same `correlationKey` (`1` in our case)
- `send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"` specifies that `normal` release operation (send to the `output-channel`) must be done on expire function when we don't have enough messages to build a whole batch (size `10` in our case). For these options, please, follow with documentation mentioned above.